# Adding equations with Greek letters using geom_text() in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

I have a small data frame which I plot and to which I want to add an equation using greek letters

```
library(tidyverse)
Beta  <- c( 1.53,  1.36,  1.24, 1.17,  1.06, 0.92, 0.84, 0.76, 0.63, 0.48)
Sigma <- c( 0.49,  0.43,  0.39, 0.37,  0.33, 0.29, 0.27, 0.24, 0.20, 0.17)
df    <- data.frame(Beta, Sigma)
```

I then plot Sigma against Beta using the following code that I modeled on [Adding equations to ggplots in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35777418/adding-equations-to-ggplots-in-r):

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Beta, y = Sigma)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method='lm', formula = y ~ x, se = FALSE, size = 0.6, color = "gray20") +
  ylab("Standard Deviation") +  
  geom_text(aes(1.0, 0.2, label=(paste(expression("sigma = 0.33 beta "*"")))),parse = TRUE)
```

This works, and gives me the text string "sigma = 0.33 beta" on my plot, but what I really want is the greek letters mu and sigma, and not the words mu and sigma. Changing the expression to "$\sigma = 0.33 \beta "*""$ (or variants of this) only gives me an error:
`Error: '\s' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""$\s"`
What is the right syntax for adding greek letters (or symbols in general) to a plot using geom_text()? I've tried `?plotmath` and it seems to suggest that `alpha` and `beta` will display as greek symbols, but they clearly do not.

Thanks in advance

Thomas Philips

Comment: I don't understand what is the asterisk after beta, is it a superscript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the plot coordinates or any other aesthetic element do not depend on the data, there is no need for `aes()`. This is the case for `geom_text` below, its arguments are all constants. And to parse the expression to be plotted as a text label is also not needed.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Beta, y = Sigma)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method='lm', formula = y ~ x, se = FALSE, size = 0.6, color = "gray20") +
  ylab("Standard Deviation") +  
  geom_text(x = 1.0, y = 0.2, 
            label = expression(sigma == "0.33" ~ beta^"*"))
```

[image]

Comment: Neat - thanks a mill. I have a follow up question: How did you determine that a) You needed two equals signs, not one, i.e. == instead of =, b) that 0.33 had to be quoted, and c) that you need a ~ before beta? I searched StackOverflow, a fair bit, as well as the help for geom_text() but didn't see this anywhere.

Comment: @ThomasPhilips The [plotmath](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/plotmath.html) help page answers to a); b) practice? c) for instance [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32465628/8245406).